# Teamviewer 11 ClientID

Tags: macos, teamviewer

I used to be able to pull the Teamviewer IDs of the Macs in my environment.

by running the following

```
ShellCommandNumberReturn(defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.TeamViewer.teamviewer10.plist ClientID)
```

With Teamviewer11 there is no teamviewer11.plist.

Does anybody know what happened, or where I can look for the 11 ClientID?